# Use of CHECK constraint in redshift tables

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, check-constraints

I have a `redshift` table with a column id which has `bigint` data type.
I want to add a constraint to check if the inserted value is positive and fail insertion if it is negative

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.new_table
(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL  ENCODE az64
    , CONSTRAINT CHK check ( id > 0 )
)
```

When I ran the query , I am getting the error

> Amazon Invalid operation: CREATE TABLE CHECK constraint is not supported; [SQL State=0A000, DB Errorcode=500310]

Any solve for this issue?

Comment: What part of the error do you not understand?  Redshift does not support check constraints.

Comment: `Redshift` doesn't force any constraints, if you have hard requirement, do the data cleansing as part part of your `ETL` script. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Defining_constraints.html

Comment: They don't enforce foreign key constraints either but they still let u define them... it would be nice for documentation purposes at least so someone looking at the ddl can understand, oh, im not supposed to do that with this table...